# Proving a Sequence Does Not Converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I have a sequence as such:

> $$\left( \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$$

Obviously it doesn't converge, because it alternates between $0,1$ for all $k$. But how do I prove this fact?

More generally, how do I prove that a sequence does not converge? Are there any neat ways other than "suppose, for contradiction, that the sequence converges. Then..."?

Comment: Did you learn the concept of subsequence?

Comment: @John Yes, I did. Would I want to use the fact that every convergent (and therefore bounded) sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent and bounded subsequence? To create a contradiction, as the sequence in question does not have such a subsequence?

Comment: If $a_n$ is convergence, then every subsequences would also converge to the same limit. But in your case, you can find two subsequences converging to different limit.

Comment: Mr.John's hint would be sufficient I guess... @Newb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of real numbers converges if and only if it's a Cauchy sequence; that is, if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that

$$n, m \ge N \implies |a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$$

If you haven't shown or seen this, I'd strongly suggest trying to prove it (or look it up in pretty much any basic analysis book).

No matter what we choose for $N$ here, however, just choose $n = N + 1$ and $m = N$, with $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then $|a_n - a_m| = 1 > \epsilon$, a contradiction.

---

Alternatively, show that if a sequence is convergent, then every subsequence is convergent to the same limit. Then choose appropriate subsequences.

Answer (score 2):

In this case (but not universally), it suffices to note that the difference between two successive terms does not converge to $0$.

Which begs the question of the reason why a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $|a_n|=1$ for every $n$, does not converge to $0$...

Comment: Well, sure - that's one of the informal definitions of convergence. But how does one show that?

Comment: You might wish to read again: this is neither "informal" nor a "definition" but a fully rigorous consequence.

Comment: Even worse, it _cannot_ work as a "definition", because it is not a sufficient condition for convergence that the successive differences tend to 0.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yep (as I said, a `consequence`).

Answer (score 1):

$\{a_k\}$ converges if and only if $\{a_{2k}\}$ and $\{a_{2k+1}\}$ converge to the same limit. Here
$$
a_{2k}=1\rightarrow1, \quad a_{2k+1}=0\rightarrow 0.
$$